# Bind Details View in Insert Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been searching everywhere to solve this and now it's time to ask.

Here's the details view:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvConnPipe" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" ForeColor="#333333"
    GridLines="None" Width="100%">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Connection Pipe 1" SortExpression="ConnectionPipe1">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtConnectionPipe1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ConnectionPipe1") %>'
                    onkeydown="return FloatOnly(event)"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtConnectionPipe1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ConnectionPipe1") %>' onkeydown="return FloatOnly(event)"></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ConnectionPipe1") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ControlStyle Width="50px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>                                    
    </Fields>  
</asp:DetailsView>
```

And a dropdown list selected index changed:

```
protected void ddlFormItem_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    DropDownList ddlFormItem = (DropDownList)sender;           
    if (ddlFormItem.SelectedValue != "-1")
    {
        int CopyID = int.Parse(ddlFormItem.SelectedValue);

        //SetInsertMode(); //If insert mode, does not bind
        //SetReadOnlyMode(); //If read only, it binds OK
        BindViews(CopyID);
    }            
}

private void BindViews(int CopyID)
{
    DataTable dt = BLL.SOCBll.GetConditions(CopyID); 
    dvConnPipe.DataSource = dt;
    dvConnPipe.DataBind();
    //More views below

}
```

It must be possible to bind a details view while in insert mode.

If I change to read only, it binds OK.

I do not want to find each control and set it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a lot of searching I did discover that you can NOT bind a detail view while in insert mode. For all the views, I had to find each control and set the default values.